# How to constraint two label

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to know how to constraint this kind of two `UILabel`.

[image]

Its easy for me when it views in `landscape`, but the `portrait` make me bother when the two `UILabel` make an equal width. This is what i get in portrait

[image]

I used auto layout. Is it possible the two label will be equal width without using code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, just hold `Control` key and drag from one label to the other, and select `Equal Width`.